# Xcode Source Control: Missing menu item. Where is the branch 'Checkout' menu option?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

In Xcode's source control pane, I used to have the menu option `Checkout` to change between git branches. I updated to Xcode 14.2. Now I can't find this menu item anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check out a branch in Xcode, perform the following steps:

1. Open the source control navigator by pressing Cmd-2.
2. Click the Repositories button at the top of the navigator.
3. Select the branch you want to check out from the list of branches.
4. Right-click to open a contextual menu.
5. Choose Switch from the contextual menu.
6. Click the Switch button in the alert that opens.

Comment: That‘s it, Apple renamed ‚Checkout‘ to ‚Switch‘